# Where do I find the source code for Bigquery library to perform a hash?

Tags: google-bigquery, hash

I'm trying to find the source code for the the [ML.HASH_BUCKETIZE](https://%20https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/bigqueryml-syntax-hash-bucketize) function.
The reason is i need to take some user id and modulo it into some buckets in another language and analyse the same data using the hash and buckets from big query.

I need to know the exact hash function they use in this function and their modulo logic so that I can code it on the app side.

One alternative i have is write my own bigquery UDF for taking the hash (say SHA-256) and then do a modulo of it but i'd rather re-use a function that they provide.